# Showing and hiding keyboard on second UITextField edit

Tags: ios, xcode

I have many UItextField, and an animation liked to them:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing: (UITextField *)textField{
NSLog(@"sowing keyboard");

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.27];
scroll1.frame = CGRectMake(0, -604, 768, 1004);
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.47];
scroll2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 414, 768, 1004);
[UIView commitAnimations];



[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{ 
                     self.mapView.alpha=0.0;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     self.mapView.hidden=YES;
                 }];


}

 -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField *)textField{
NSLog(@"hiding keyboard");

if (scroll2.frame.origin.y != 414) {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.27];
scroll1.frame = CGRectMake(0, -340, 768, 1004);
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.47];
scroll2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 678, 768, 1004);
[UIView commitAnimations];

[self.mapView setHidden:NO];

//fade in
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

[self.mapView setAlpha:1.0];

[UIView commitAnimations];

    }
}
```

The problem is that if I am editing a field, and from their i touch and start to edit another field, the code didEnd and then DidBegin are called. How can I stop that?? I would like these animations only to occur when i start editing a text field and no text fields are being edited, and the DidEnd when I need to hide the keyboard (when the user presses the DownKey on iPad)

Any ideas??

I tried this:

```
if (scroll2.frame.origin.y != 414) {
```

...it works but when I press the rerun key, no animation occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textField in question sends itself along with the argument to textFieldDidBeginEditing.

Add an if () block to test for textField1 and textField2 ie:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if (textField == textField1) {
    //do animation linked to textField1
}
if (textField == textField2) {
    //do animation linked to textField2
}
}
```

Also, you should implement this method

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    //handles the enter/done key
    //perform whatever action for when user touches return
    if (textField == textField1) {
        [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [textField1 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES or NO;
}
```

Comment: This method does not work... is there a way to detect if the user taps on a uItextField while another is being edited?

Comment: If you're copying and pasting verbatim it won't work, you have to replace textField1 and textField2 with the instance variable names of your textFields. UITextField does have a readOnly bool property for if it's currently in edit mode, I believe